# Is there a name for linear transformations $T: C(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, operator-theory

Briefly, I wish to study forms that can approximate all such linear transformations $T: C(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Clearly the Riesz representation theorem cannot be applied in this case as $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not the field of the Hilbert space $C(\mathbb{R})$, nor can I apply the thoerems I yet know in operator theory as $T$ does not map $C(\mathbb{R})$ to itself.

So I'd like to know the name of such transformations as $T$, so that I can possibly learn about their representations.(I had an idea that for any $T$, one representation might be as follows:
$$T(x) = \sum_i^n \pmb{e}_i \langle x, w_i\rangle $$for $w_i \in C(\mathbb{R})$.

Tell me if I'm totally barking up the wrong tree here. Thanks.

Comment: Since all norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent, these are exactly vectors consisting of linear functionals.

Comment: So it would suffice to use the Riesz representation theorem to thereby suggest that any $T$ can be approximated by the form I've given ($\sum_i^n \pmb{e}_i \langle x, w_i \rangle$)? @Ian

Comment: It isn't approximate; that's exact. It follows readily from the fact that if $\pi_i(x)=x_i$ then $\pi_i \circ T$ is a linear functional.